# How do I keep my "validity" row always updated in relation to my "expiration date" row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

This is my database's `survey` table:
[image]

I learned to use `CURDATE()` and `DATEADD()`, so the table can now automatically calculate the `survey_date` and its `expiration_date`.

But I'd also like to add a value to my `validity` column.
My validity column is a `BIT(1)`.
I'd like 1 to represent a Valid Survey, and a 0 to represent an Invalid Survey.

How do I make it so that the `validity` column is always correct in relationship to my `expiration_date` column?
I want it to change depending on the date, so 
it's correct all the time, instead of only being correct when I first insert the row.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the logic for the validity column?

Comment: @GordonLinoff If CURDATE() > expiration_date, then validity 0. However, if CURDATE() < or = expiration_date, then validity 1. I guess that would be it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice if you could add this using a generated column

```
alter table survey
    add validity bit generated always as (expiration_date < now());
```

However, that is not allowed, because `now()` is a volatile function (i.e., it changes value every time it is called).

You need to use a view:

```
create view v_survey as 
    select s.*,
           (expiration_date < now()) as is_valid
    from survey;
```